# how to use smooth scroll via jquery and using a class?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I've been working on this for a while and I'm pretty much lost. For the second part of the code (which is labeled), I have an anchor tag (< a >) with a **class name**. I want to create a smooth scroll to an element via the class name. I need to use jquery per what I am required to do. I have tried a different method and cannot seem to get this to work.

Per the HTML the

```
 <a class="js--scroll" href="#">I’m hungry </a>
```

this is where the button is that will be click to go to the section of the website that we want

```
<section class="js--where-i-should-scroll-to">
```

this is the area in which I want to scroll

The jquery I am attempting to use:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // for sticky nav
  $(".class1").waypoint(
    function (direction) {
      if (direction == "down") {
        $("nav").addClass("sticky");
      } else {
        $("nav").removeClass("sticky");
      }
    },
    {
      offset: "100px;",
    }
  );
```

**PART 2 of JQuery**

```
  var $root = $("html, body");

  $('a[href^=\\"#"]').click(function () {
    var href = $.attr(this, "href");

    $root.animate(
      {
        scrollTop: $(href).offset().top,
      },
      500,
      function () {
        window.location.hash = href;
      }
    );
});
```

NOTE: I am trying to smooth scroll via a class in the last part of the HTML
NOTE: I'm using jquery v3.6.0

Answer (score 0):

you can do this task only using CSS,
Just add CSS code

```
html {
scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Create hyperlink and section:

```
<a href="#whereToScroll">GO TO</a>


<!-- The Page scrolled to here -->
<a name="whereToScroll"></a>
<section>
...
</section>
```

Comment: So, your saying there no way to add smooth scrilling via  JQUERY  when using class. my understanding is that the aboce code isnt supported for all broswers thus dong a cross browers will require jquery?

Answer (score 0):

In your **HTML:-**

you have to define an id for your section

```
<section id="js--where-i-should-scroll-to">
```

Then navigate to it using the hyperlink, also give your `<a>` tag `rel="relativeanchor"` for query selector

```
 <a class="js--scroll" href="#js--where-i-should-scroll-to" rel="relativeanchor">I’m hungry </a>
```

In your **JQuery PART 2**

Try changing it to the following:-

```
$('a[rel="relativeanchor"]').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
```

Here is a fully working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/736dmug9/8/) of what you want to achieve

Comment: https://codepen.io/Sleven_/pen/JjWLReW

can you please look atr my code i havent been able to resolve this issue

Comment: I've looked in your codepen link, you have 2 issues:- First, You didn't use an `id` in your `href` attr. Second, You were importing `waypoint` in a wrong way. I've a copy of your code working with sticky navbar here => [Fiddle Code](https://jsfiddle.net/dv5g7xs9/3/) <=

Comment: I got it to work via fiddle but in VS code live-server only the top half of the code works, the smooth scrolling doesnt work for somw  some reason. anu ideas on why

Comment: Thank you for all your help btw

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work. I had to remove overflow hidden from both  the body and the HTML

```
HTML, body{
overflow: hidden
}
```

It Will not work. It will stop the jquery from running the animation for smooth-scroll. Instead, you will have to add overflow: hidden to either the body or the HTML but not both. I recommend trying both out because it will affect your site in different ways.

corrected code

```
html{
overflow:hidden
}
```

or

```
   body{
    overflow:hidden
    }
```